# How can I add a command to initramfs / initrd to execute before mounting the root partition?

Tags: boot, scripts, encryption, initrd

ubuntu 18.04 64-bit

I have a setup which has three separate block crypt devices, plus a non-encrypted /boot. If I had started with a clean sheet of paper, I could have done it with two, but it would be a science project to reformat everything now.

On boot, the scripts in initramfs ask for the passphrase for each separately, I would like to add my own script in which I prompt for it once, and decrypt all the drives / partitions in one shot, pre-empting the system script, and allowing me to use a more complex one that CBP can't brute force :)

I am struggling to figure out where to put it.

I have had a look at a bunch of stuff, and it talks a lot about how to run update-initramfs and the scripts executed then when generating the initrd file, but not how to add content to initramfs itself. I could manually unpack and repack the initrd file, but that is not compatible with the system tools like update-initramfs, and best case I'd have to redo it every kernel upgrade or other post-install trigger.

I was kinda hoping for a folder like init/rc3.d where I could just drop it and use a sequence number to get it executed early.